Video doesn't to be compressed for firebase if has more than 7 seconds
I am making a page where my user is adding videos to his profile but when I to upload them to firebase I receive this
flutter:

Error uploading trailer video: [firebase_storage/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. Message too long.

I want to know what package I can use or what I should to so videos that have 30 seconds or more can be uploaded to firebase
This is the code I used for this functionality , any advice?
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Add Trailer Video',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text(
                'Select a video from your gallery',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    await _pickAndUploadTrailerVideo();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Choose Video',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _pickAndUploadTrailerVideo() async {
    try {
      final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      final XFile? video = await picker.pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxDuration: const Duration(minutes: 5), // Limit video duration to 5 minutes
      );

      if (video == null) return;

      // Show loading indicator
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );

      // Create a unique filename
      String uniqueFileName = 'program_trailers/${widget.program.id}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';
      
      // Get reference to storage
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(uniqueFileName);
      
      // Upload file with metadata
      final metadata = SettableMetadata(
        contentType: 'video/mp4',
        customMetadata: {'programId': widget.program.id},
      );
      
      // Upload the video
      final uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(File(video.path), metadata);

      // Listen to upload progress
      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen(
        (TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
          double progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;
          print('Upload progress: ${(progress * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)}%');
        },
        onError: (e) {
          Navigator.pop(context); // Dismiss loading indicator
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Error uploading video: $e')),
          );
        },
      );

      // Wait for upload to complete
      await uploadTask;
      
      // Get download URL
      final downloadURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
      
      // Update Firestore document
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .doc(widget.program.id)
          .update({
        'trailerVideoUrl': downloadURL,
        'trailerVideoPath': uniqueFileName,
        'trailerVideoAddedAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });

      // Dismiss loading indicator
      Navigator.pop(context);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Trailer video uploaded successfully')),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // Dismiss loading indicator if still showing
      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
      
      print('Error uploading trailer video: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error uploading trailer video')),
      );
    }
  }
}
Future<void> _pickAndUploadTrailerVideo() async {
    try {
      final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      final XFile? video = await picker.pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxDuration: const Duration(minutes: 5), // Limit video duration to 5 minutes
      );

      if (video == null) return;

      // Show loading indicator
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );

      // Create a unique filename
      String uniqueFileName = 'program_trailers/${widget.program.id}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';
      
      // Get reference to storage
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(uniqueFileName);
      
      // Upload file with metadata
      final metadata = SettableMetadata(
        contentType: 'video/mp4',
        customMetadata: {'programId': widget.program.id},
      );
      
      // Upload the video
      final uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(File(video.path), metadata);

      // Listen to upload progress
      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen(
        (TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
          double progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;
          print('Upload progress: ${(progress * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)}%');
        },
        onError: (e) {
          Navigator.pop(context); // Dismiss loading indicator
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Error uploading video: $e')),
          );
        },
      );

      // Wait for upload to complete
      await uploadTask;
      
      // Get download URL
      final downloadURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
      
      // Update Firestore document
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .doc(widget.program.id)
          .update({
        'trailerVideoUrl': downloadURL,
        'trailerVideoPath': uniqueFileName,
        'trailerVideoAddedAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });

      // Dismiss loading indicator
      Navigator.pop(context);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Trailer video uploaded successfully')),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // Dismiss loading indicator if still showing
      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
      
      print('Error uploading trailer video: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error uploading trailer video')),
      );
    }
  }
}

